# get number from a string after trimming 0 using Regex c#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a namestring like ( This is a file name  stored in server)

> Offer_2018-06-05_PROSP000033998_20180413165327.02155000.NML.050618.1040.67648.0

The file name format is given above.  I need to get the number  out of

> PROSP000033998

and remove the leading zeros  ( 33998)   using Regex in C# . there are different values that will come instead of PROSP.  So i want to use a regex to get the number instead of string split. Tried using `(0|[1-9]\d*)`, but not sure whether this is correct as i got 2018 as the output

```
  Regex regexLetterOfOffer = new Regex (@"0|[1-9]\d*");
                            Match match = regexLetterOfOffer.Match (fileInfo.Name);
                            if (match.Success)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine (match.Value);
                            }
```

Comment: What happened when you used that regex?

Comment: i got 2018 , not  33998

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use a regex here; it may be easier and more readable to split the string by `_`, then trim the first five characters off the third element of that array.

Comment: @HarryCutts, Thanks for the suggestion .  I am particularly  trying to use regex instead of the split string method

Comment: Could you edit your question to explain why? It sounds like that's an important thing for us to know.

Comment: It would also help to see the code you're using the regex in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generalized regular expression for alphabetical characters, possibly followed by zeros, then capturing digits with an underscore afterwards could be

```
[A-Z]0*([1-9]\d*)(?=_)
```

That is:

```
Regex regexLetterOfOffer = new Regex (@"[A-Z]0*([1-9]\d*)(?=_)");
Match match = regexLetterOfOffer.Match("Offer_2018-06-05_PROSP000033998_20180413165327.02155000.NML.050618.1040.67648.0");
if (match.Success)
{
  Console.WriteLine (match.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

This will match similar strings whose digit sequences start with something other than `PROSP`.

Comment: This is  a better solution . The  generic one can be reused.

Comment: Can i have  _ or  . to be checked 
Example
`INSTFULL_405151220.02140401 
DDAMDLTR_405109632_20181120
PHONEREC_12345`
I am looking for the number between _ and . or _ and _ which ever comes first

Comment: If there are only two underscores, you could use `_(\d+)[_.]` https://regex101.com/r/u9fUv6/1

Answer (score 1):

Putting `(0|[1-9]\d*)` into https://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/ shows that it is actually matching the number you want, it's just also matching all the other numbers in the string. [The `Match` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) only returns the first one, 2018 in this case. To only match the part you're after, you could use `PROSP0*([1-9]\d*)` as the regex. The brackets `()` around the last part make it a *capturing group*, which you can retrieve using the `Groups` property of the `Match` object:

```
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value)
```

(Group 0 is the whole match, hence we want group 1.)

Comment: That Worked . Thank you

Comment: No problem :-). If this is for production code, not just learning, though, I'd seriously suggest using the splitting solution I mentioned in [my other comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51663769/get-number-from-a-string-after-trimming-0-using-regex-c-sharp/51663904#comment90290969_51663769). Regexes are generally harder to understand than other solutions to a problem.

Comment: This is for production code, and also an attempt to learn  Regex.  If anything breaks, i know what function to blame now :)